# What is the best way to raise validation exception in Grid Cell, Grid Row, Form View and on Saving?

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

What is the best way to raise validation exception in Grid Cell, Grid Row, Form View and on Saving?

For field level, I am putting fieldVerifying and raise PropertySetException it show exception on field with red mark.
On saving handle RowPersisting event, it raise exception if any validation fail it will show alert message, but not showing on cell or row or field.
Is it good way to handle validation exception?
May you suggest any batter way to handle validation exception?

Should we put validation exception in RowPersisting(to avoid wrong data saving) as well as FieldVerifying?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cache.RaiseExceptionHandling` instead of throwing an exception in RowPersisting event to highlight the field with the error sign. 
You can also control where the error sign appears by specifying Error Level, like that:
`sender.RaiseExceptionHandling<DAC.field>(e.Row, sender.GetValueExt<DAC.field>(e.Row), new PXSetPropertyException(message, PXErrorLevel.Error));`

PXErrorLevel.Error will set the error sign on the field, PXErrorLevel.RowError will mark the entire row in the grid with the error sign.

Depending on the UI requirement you can either keep the verification on FieldVerifying, or you can do both FieldVerifying and RowPersisting

Comment: It is working Ok, but when i use exception logic into the screen where Revision number logic implemented then Grid rows clear and data has been saved and nothing is shown into row/field in UI(validation checking into RowPersisting event). 
Code using in RowPersisting event
e.Cancel = true;
sender.RaiseExceptionHandling<DAC.field>(e.Row, sender.GetValueExt<DAC.field>(e.Row), new PXSetPropertyException(message, PXErrorLevel.Error)); what is the best way to show the error into that screen?

Comment: It looks like there is something else that is wrong there. Either you use that on one of key fields

Comment: No, Not key field, same thing happening in Bill of material, You can look into that form also. Please give suggestion to resolve that issue.

Comment: I am using new release acumatica 20 version, In RowPersisting event, I am raising exception like  sender.RaiseExceptionHandling<DAC.field>(e.Row, sender.GetValueExt<DAC.field>(e.Row), new PXSetPropertyException(message, PXErrorLevel.Error)); and also setting Cancel true, But data is reset and save button disabled Evan raise exception. It was not happening in 19, Any reason?

Comment: To avoid saving data on RowPersisting and resetting the value by NewValue and Save button must be enable until all validation pass, what should i do?